# How to move iPhoto library to external drive

Tags: macos, photos.app

I'm needing to free up space on my Mac and I have a migrated iPhoto library of 178 GB that I would like to move to an external drive as I'm too scared to delete it. However, it won't let me move it across to the hard drive - it just pings back to it's location.

Looking for advice please on what to do with this iPhoto library.

Comment: How are you moving it to the external drive? Can you create a new folder on the target drive (to verify that you are allowed to create folders/files there)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't create a new folder on the external drive and I've since discovered it's in a 'read only' format, for some unknown reason! I've borrowed a different external drive and it moved first time! So, I've solved one problem and found another :-(

Comment: How was the first drive formatted? Mac won't natively write to NTFS.